# My android app is crashing - says null pointer exception in logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

Error message..

> 2021-09-06 12:13:35.750 12573-12573/com.example.getnews E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.getnews, PID: 12573
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.example.getnews.NewsModel.getArticles()' on a null object reference
>
> at com.example.getnews.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:88)
> at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
> at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$hVGjmafRi6VitDIrPNdoFizVAdk.run(Unknown Source:6)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

This is the exact error in logcat.

My mainActivity method code

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsModel>()  {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsModel> call, retrofit2.Response<NewsModel> response) throws NullPointerException{

                NewsModel newsModal = response.body();
                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                ArrayList<Articles> articlesArrayList= newsModal.getArticles();
                for (int i = 0; i < articlesArrayList.size(); i++){
                    articles.add(new Articles(articlesArrayList.get(i).getTitle(), articlesArrayList.get(i).getDescription(), articlesArrayList.get(i).getUrlToImage(), articlesArrayList.get(i).getUrl(), articlesArrayList.get(i).getContent()));
                }
                newsRVAapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewsModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail to get response..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Please help - I am a beginner and I have tried most of the solutions in web and I have tried to solve but the solutions are specific, the application is failing to start...says stopped unexpectedly

Comment: It seems like you newsModal is null,  please check if you are getting the response in that.         
Tip not the solution : Add null check on newsModel before adding it to array list to avoid crash in case of empty newsModal.

Comment: You are getting null pointer exception add try-catch.Also you are getting null with newsModal.getArticles();

Comment: Response is null

Comment: your `response.body();` return null. Please debug it or check on postman.

Answer (score -1):

it seems you are getting no data in response against articles. So, make your articles nullable in com.example.getnews.NewsModel and before adding to array, just add null check to avoid crash and in null case you may show empty view.

Copy and paste following code in onResponse method.

```
ArrayList<Articles> articlesArrayList = new ArrayList();
if(newsModel.getArticles() != null){
    for (int i = 0; i < articlesArrayList.size(); i++){
        articles.add(new Articles(articlesArrayList.get(i).getTitle(), 
        articlesArrayList.get(i).getDescription(), 
        articlesArrayList.get(i).getUrlToImage(), 
        articlesArrayList.get(i).getUrl(), 
        articlesArrayList.get(i).getContent()));
    }
}

newsRVAapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This would still crash, as `newsModel` is null. (As `response.body()` returned null.)

Comment: please provide your model and json response.

Comment: Thanks for y'all responses!